# If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and has a local maximum at $c$, prove that $f'\left( c\right) =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

let $I$ be an open interval, $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $c\in I$. The function $f$ is said to have a *local maximum* at $c$ if and only if there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f\left( c\right) \geq f\left( x\right)$ holds for all $\left| x-c\right| <\delta$.

*Propositon*. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and has a local maximum at $c$, prove that $f'\left( c\right) =0$.

Proof-trying. Assume $f$ is differentiable at $c$, i.e.,

$lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {f\left( h+c\right) -f\left(c\right)} {h}=f'\left(c\right)$

exist.

Assume $f$ has a local maximum at $c$, i.e.,

$\dfrac {f\left( u+c\right) -f\left(c\right)} {u}\leq 0$ for $u>0$ and

$\dfrac {f\left( t+c\right) -f\left(c\right)} {t}\geq 0$ for $t<0$.

**So, what should I do?**

Comment: How about assuming $f'(c)>0$ in the beginning and looking at the definition to see what you would get?

Comment: You should probably consult one of thousands of calculus books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can you say about
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}
$$
based on the inequalities you wrote down? On the other hand, the two limits are equal by assumption.

**Lemma.** *Suppose $g$ is defined over $(c,d)$, that $g(x)\ge0$ for $x\in(c,d)$ and that $\lim_{x\to c^+}g(x)=l$ exists finite. Then $l\ge0$.*

*Proof.* Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $l<0$. Then, by definition, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $x\in(c,c+\delta)$,
$$
|g(x)-l|<-\frac{l}{2}
$$
In particular
$$
g(x)-l<-\frac{l}{2}
$$
so $g(x)<l/2<0$. Contradiction.

Prove the similar statements for $g(x)\le0$ and for limits from the left.

Now, if $c$ is a local maximum, we have
$$
f'(c)=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$
On the other hand, by the above lemma and the similar statements,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\ge0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\le0
$$
Therefore $f'(c)\ge0$ and $f'(c)\le0$. The only possibility is thus $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: how can I use 'f has a local max at $c$' here?

Comment: The two inequalities tell you that the function you compute the limit from the left is nonnegative, so its limit is $\ge0$; the limit from the right is likewise $\le0$. Hence…

Comment: Hence, by the squeeze lemma $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: @Kahler No squeeze lemma; the only number $x$ that satisfies both $x\ge0$ and $x\le0$ is $x=0$.

Comment: I stil have a question. Let $f\left( x\right) =\left| x\right|$. So,$ f\left( 0^-\right) =-1$ and $f\left( 0^+\right) =1$. Thus, $f'\left( 0^-\right)$ is not $\geq 0$ and  $f'\left( 0^+\right)$ is not $\leq 0$.

Comment: @Kahler The function is not differentiable at $0$. The function in your question is differentiable at $c$ by assumption.